# android service broadcast (a reminding function)

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, broadcast

I want to have a reminding function(by set reminding time) in my app ,using notification. And I get to know that there may used service, broadcast and alarmmanger,

How can I complete this function ?

I think there are two ways:

1. use the service ,and the notification is in service
2. use the service to send broadcast,and the notification is in broadcastReceiver

the first question:

1. which way is right or better?
2. how to use that alarmmanager ? is that like the Timer class in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest and most efficient way would be to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for something like reminders. You will need to make a [BroadCastReceiver](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) that receives your alarm. Your receiver can make the [notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html), since the `onReceive()` method of the receiver also takes in a `Context` parameter. To make the Alarm, you will have to get an instance of the AlarmManager Class, make a PendingIntent with what you need, then actually set the Alarm.

Sample Code for setting an Alarm

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id,  intent, //makes a new intent
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //only updates PendingIntent, does not recreate
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pendIntent); //used to cancel if previously active
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToExec, //sets the alarm to exectute once
             pendIntent);
```

Comment: don't need service ?   it can make notification when the app is down?

Comment: Yes, straight from the AlarmManager API: "Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running."